# Packages to acoustically localise animals with microphone arrays

Tags: terrestrial, localisation, time-difference-of-arrival, array, tracking

I'm looking to localise vocalising (terrestrial) animals (in my case bat calls) based on time-difference-of-arrivals with an open-source package (preferably written in an open-source language too).

Till now I've only encountered custom-written inhouse software in publications (e.g. TOADSuite and Batalef). The [PAMGuard](https://www.pamguard.org/11_PluginModules.html#Localisers) package seems to focus on tracking in aquatic settings. Some other packages developed for birds (e.g. [SoundFinder](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/09524622.2013.827588?casa_token=JbokDe0iDGoAAAAA:PZgLenDKofq_N40B_z2b-V5o_fo2o21q5E4s_GwWsWHDhd-j1ao_vKcJA82D92U6GjHfMVI0XQZIRQk) aren't active anymore.

Is anyone aware of a recent open-source package geared towards terrestrial acoustic localisation?
(Would appreciate No as a valid answer!). I'm currently contemplating doing further work on a package I'm writing for myself and gauging community interest here too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a list of localization software [here](https://github.com/rhine3/bioacoustics-software/blob/main/README.md) (see the "Acoustic localization" section). It started from a [review](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ece3.6216) of methods for terrestrial acoustic localization. I tried to only include software that either is stable, currently in active development, or was recently released.

As you have found, the options are pretty limited, especially for software geared toward terrestrial applications! SoundFinder's Excel and R versions are still workable, although they are no longer under active development.

Software that my lab developed, OpenSoundscape, has an [acoustic localization module](https://opensoundscape.org/en/latest/api/modules.html#module-opensoundscape.localization) that is geared toward terrestrial localization, but the algorithms and use aren't fully documented with examples yet. (Something that we've been working on this summer.)

Answer (score 2):

Contact "Lasse Jakobsen" of University of Southern Denmark, he developed a MatLab app specifically for this. It has been used in several studies since (see link to google search below).

Good luck

(link to google search for bat localiser app: https://www.google.com/search?q=moonshine+bat+localisation+lasse&client=firefox-b-d&ei=CYe0YsDZJYvcgAa_tZBY&ved=0ahUKEwiAgoqM8sP4AhULLsAKHb8aBAsQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=moonshine+bat+localisation+lasse&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToHCAAQRxCwAzoHCCEQChCgAUoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDgBFjtDGDSFWgBcAF4AIABmwGIAf4FkgEDMC42mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)

Comment: thanks for the answer @2sloth. I have seen Lasse's code in action (think it's called 'Moonshine'?), and I'm sure he'd be happy to share the code too! I'm looking for projects developed along modern open-source practices e.g. like PAMGuard, with documentation, tutorials, etc. that are potentially extendable to my needs. Also, Lasse's package is MATLAB based (as are TOADSuite and Batalef), and I've updated the question to highlight the open-source language requirement too.

Comment: Youight be able to run it in GNU Octave, an open source MATLAB clone. Good luck